# Battery status seems to be stuck

Tags: 15.10, laptop, power-management, battery, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 3000 series with Ubuntu 15.10. I noticed a few hours ago that the battery status remained unchanged (at 45%) and it said 1:40 hours left for full charge. I tried removing and reinserting the battery, restarted several times, but nothing worked. Then I ran the laptop on battery power for a short while when the charge came down to 29%. Then I plugged in the charger again and now the status is stuck at 29%! What is going on with my system? How can I fix this?

[image]
<sup>**Battery stuck at 29%**</sup>